# how to write a if condition within a select statement?

Tags: sql, select, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a column which needs to be populated with ture/false/(N/A) data. This column is part of a select statement
So, How can i achieve this?

```
SELECT distinct 
program_id, 
prog_name,
Eitc_Active_Switch as Prog_Status,
progmap.client_id,
progmap.ORG_ID,
sec.calwinexists_ind as interface,
sec.Client_name
FROM ref_programs prog (nolock)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ref_county_program_map progmap (nolock)         
ON progmap.program_id=prog.prog_id AND progmap.CLIENT_ID=prog.CLIENT_ID 
INNER join sec_clients sec (nolock)
on sec.client_id=progmap.Client_id
```

'sec.calwinexists_ind as interface' is the column. the true/false should be displayed for only three records (AMC, AMBD, ACMNI) and 'N/A'
for the rest of the records

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To use code tags, highlight the text and press the button that looks like this `{}` OR indent your text by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use [CASE](http://www.coderecipes.net/sql-case-expression-tutorial.aspx) expression.

Example:

```
SELECT name,salary,
CASE    
WHEN  salary <= 2000 THEN 'low'
WHEN  salary > 2000 AND salary <= 3000 THEN 'average'
WHEN  salary > 3000 THEN 'high'
END AS salary_level
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary ASC
```

And in this way you should adapt your query to match your needs.

Comment: Is there a way to add 'Else' i.e. default statement?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a CASE WHEN control. Take a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/pt/control-flow-functions.html